# Transition Effect on iPhone from Safari to App Store

Tags: ios4, core-animation

Is there anyone know how I can make/use the Transition effect (on iPhone) that happens when I click an iPhone app link on Safari ?

The transition is like swapping of two screens.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 stock transitions I know of, Curl and Flip. I don't know if apple has published that one. You can always make it yourself.

Comment: I saw that the stated Transition is also used in the application "Friended".

Comment: Really? They may have coded it themselves. It seems in general that the transition is implemented into the OS itself and is only used when an app switches from one app to another. I will check out the app you mentioned. But at this point, I think you may end up coding this yourself. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.